# Straight line depreciation using a for loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm not sure where my code is going wrong on this one. the listbox is supposed to display like:

```
   0       10,000.00               0.00           0.00
   1        8,000.00           2,000.00       2,000.00
   2        6,000.00           2,000.00       4,000.00
   3        4,000.00           2,000.00       6,000.00
   4        2,000.00           2,000.00       8,000.00
   5            0.00           2,000.00      10,000.00
```

But it comes out like this:

```
   0        8,000.00               0.00       2,000.00
   1        6,000.00           2,000.00       4,000.00
   2        4,000.00           2,000.00       6,000.00
   3        2,000.00           2,000.00       8,000.00
   4            0.00           2,000.00      10,000.00
   5        -2000.00           2,000.00      12,000.00
```

I cant seem to figure out what is going on as i am new to c#. Here is my code:

```
    private void ComputeDepreciation(double AssetValue,double years)
    {
        double AnnualDepreciation, TotalDepreciation;
        AnnualDepreciation = 0;
        TotalDepreciation = 0;
        AnnualDepreciation = AssetValue / years;
        for (years = 0; years <= double.Parse(textBox2.Text); years++)
        {
            AssetValue = AssetValue - AnnualDepreciation;
            TotalDepreciation = TotalDepreciation + AnnualDepreciation;
            lstOutput.Items.Add(String.Format(strOutput, years, AssetValue, AnnualDepreciation, TotalDepreciation));
        }
    }
```

Please Help!

Comment: It seems you want TotalDepreciation is zero at first row, but your for loop doing the operation from year 0. You may set start index from 1 rather than 0, and put first row out of the loop.

Comment: Your argument `double years` isn't used at all, instead, you are reading in from a text box with `double.Parse(textBox2.Text)`. Don't do that, separate your calculation from the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

[image: scr1]

<sub>Make sure you set the font to monospace style so the column formatting is preserved.</sub>

You can fill the `ListBox` by setting its `.DataSource` property into a collection of strings, just like the button click method below. Also, it is recommended to use `decimal` for anything money related to avoiding any silliness like `1.199999999997` for an amount.

```
private IList<string> ComputeDepreciation(decimal assetValue, int noYears)
{
    List<string> table = new List<string>();
    // Add header
    table.Add($"{"Yrs",3} {"Asset Value",15} {"Actual Depr.",18} {"Total Depr.",14}");
    // Year 0 values
    int year = 0;
    decimal totalDepreciation = 0m;
    decimal actualDepreciation, annualDepreciation = assetValue/noYears;
    do
    {
        // Cannot depreciate more than the value
        actualDepreciation = Math.Min(annualDepreciation, assetValue);

        // Add formatted row with column widths 3, 15, 18, 14
        // Currency formatted with "C2", two decimals and currency symbol.
        table.Add($"{year,3} {assetValue,15:C2} {actualDepreciation,18:C2} {totalDepreciation,14:C2}");

        // adjust values each year
        assetValue -= actualDepreciation;
        totalDepreciation += actualDepreciation;
        year++;

    } while (actualDepreciation>0m);

    return table;
}
private void fillButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.DataSource = ComputeDepreciation(10000m, 5);
}
```